# Polynomials agreeing on the boundary of the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $h(z)=z\frac{p(z^{-1})}{q(z^{-1})}$ satisfying:

- $\deg(p)=\deg(q)>1$
- $|p(z)|=|q(z)|$ for $|z|=1$
- $\forall w_0,z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $p(z_0)=0, q(w_0)=0$, one has $|w_0|,|z_0|<1$ .

Is $h(z)=cz$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|c|=1$?

By Maximum Modulus Principle, $h$ attains its maximum at the boundary of the unit disk, hence $|h(z)|\leq|z|$ for $|z|\leq1$.

Comment: Assuming that my hypotheses are correct, I am thinking of perhaps applying Scharwz Lemma, but not too sure where to start.

Comment: *Hint:* (i) $|z - \alpha| = |1 - \overline{\alpha}z|$ for $|z| = 1$ and (ii) The maximum and 'minimum' modulus principle.

Comment: @r9m sorry, but I don't quite catch your hints. I presume that $\alpha$ here means the roots of the polynomials? If so, why does $|z-\alpha|=|1-z\bar\alpha|$ as $|\alpha|\neq 1$?

Comment: (i) gives on the unit circle $|P(z)| = |c|\prod_{j=1}^n |1 - \overline{\alpha_j} z|$; the polynomial $\tilde{P}(z) = c\prod_{j=1}^n (1 - \overline{\alpha_j} z)$ has all it's roots outside the unit disk. Similarly for $\tilde{Q}$ as well. Thus $R(z) := \tilde{P}(z)/\tilde{Q}(z)$ is non vanishing in unit disk and $|R(z)| = 1 $ on $|z| = 1$. What can you conclude from here?

Comment: @r9m, by Maximum and Minimum Modulus Principle, since $R(z)$ has no zeroes inside the unit disk, thus $|R(z)|=1$ for all $|z|\leq 1$.

Comment: Yes ..this implies $R(z) = c$ in disk where $|c| = 1$ is some constant, proving $P(z) = cQ(z)$ for $|c| = 1$.Now to see (i) note that $|z - \alpha| = |\overline{z} - \overline{\alpha}| = |\overline z|\left|1 - \frac{\overline{\alpha} |z|^2}{\overline z}\right| = |1 - \overline{\alpha}z|$ when $|z| = 1$.

Comment: @r9m Thanks alot.